# no puedo usar checkboxes en vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hola he intentado de la forma en la que la documentacion de vue indica y funciona con una variable aun no asignada a la hora que asigno,

```
                           <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check- 
                                input" value="lunes"
                                v-model="usuario.condiciones">
                                Lunes
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check- 
                               input" value="martes"
                                v-model="usuario.condiciones">
                                Martes
                                </label>
                            </div>
                             <br>
                                 <p><strong>Dias: </strong> 
                                 {{usuario.condiciones}}</p>

                            <script>
                 data (){
                        return {
                      usuario: {

                      condiciones: []
                  },
```

esto recoje el arreglo.

cuando al objeto usuario lo cambio por una variable ya asignada y funcionando en un campo de la DB. deja de funcionar no se que hacer ya.

otra es asignar directamente sin convertir en colección de objetos pero lo unico que hacen los checkboxes es al mismo tiempo llenarse y solo da valores booleanos.

gracias y saludos a todos

Comment: Ese problema esta descripto en el manual de vue. como es un objeto, no le podes asignar valores asi nomas. lo tenes que hacer con un object.set.. buscalo en el manual.

Comment: gracias lo checare

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?